# Nginx configuration: autoindex subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I'm newbie to nginx.

I need to autoindex directories on my webserver, include subdirecties.
So, i configure my niginx like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  collect.funshion.com;
    root         /home/html;
    access_log  /home/nginx/access.log;
    #charset koi8-r;                                                       

    location / {                                                          
        autoindex                   on;
        autoindex_exact_size        off;
        autoindex_localtime         on;
    }
}
```

but it only works on root directory /, it confused me...

Comment: when i access subdirs, just got 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you're getting 403 forbidden, could it be that the nginx user does not have sufficient rights on the subdirs?

Comment: Yeah, finally i found this problem is caused due to insufficient right, thanks very much.

Comment: You can debug www-data access easily with this command: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375873